# UWP : How to run a Service infinitly on a Windows Phone

Tags: win-universal-app, background-task, background-service

I have gone through various articles on Background Tasks. But none could solve my use case: **Running a service infinitely on Windows Phone**

1) Is it even possible to do that (consider that I have the OEM Account with Microsoft).

2) I know this is wrong as it would drain the battery, etc... but is it even possible.

3) Also the service should start when the phone starts up.

4) I have read about registering background tasks which run periodically, or on System triggers. But they don't seem to work for me.

5) The service should run even if the App is closed, suspended.

6) Windows Runtime Component(Tried using it) is fine but it's not what I want.

Any pointers ?

**UPDATE:**  Consider that I open the weather App, it registers a background task which updates the weather periodically. But what I want is there is no actual App(Which registers my background task). I am an OEM(say ASUS) and I want to flash a Service which starts when the phone is started for the first time and sends me information and it runs even after restart and even after factory reset because it was on the image which I used to flash the device Now Is that possible?

The above example explains my use case more clearly (updated as suggested by Alexej).

Thanks!

Comment: BackgroundTasks are run infinitly even if app closed/suspended. Only in some conditions they are stopped. And also they have limits (in another case they could slow down perfomance) What are you want to do in your service? How much processor time is it required?

Comment: @AlexejSommer My service basically will collect some information(say data like Wifi status, etc..) and send to a remote server for analysis. I know that I can keep on collecting data and send it periodically say in every 1 hour. But how do I ensure it will run on every startup. I want the service to be there always even if it sends data periodically. Can I just flash service on the phone and how? I don't need any app as I don't want to capture any app specific data.

Answer (score 1):

In standard WP settings you can find this:

[image]

That's app with background tasks. Nothing else. They are start after phone start. But they have limits (just not to slow down phone). There is no other way to do it on phone.
As I have understand you need [TimeTrigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br224843). You can run it every hour.
But you can not be 100% sure that it will work. Remember about limitations. Performance is at first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Yes I know about Background Tasks and their limitations. For example, I open the weather App, it registers a background task which updates the weather periodically. But what I want is there is no actual App(Which registers my background task). I am an OEM(say ASUS) and I want to flash a Service which starts when the phone is started for the first time and sends me information and it runs even after restart and even after factory reset coz it was on the image which I used to flash the device Now Is that possible?

Comment: Please update your question with information from this comment. It's would be more clear. I don't think that it's exist any possibility to flash your WP like you want. It looks unsafe.